# RouteData.Values["xxx"] generates error inside asp.net user Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, webforms

I am trying to update my asp.net webform based website to use Routing feature but i am failing to fix one error inside userControl.ascx.

I can access query string value in main page using `RouteData.Values["language"].ToString()` but same fails when i need to use the query string value inside a user control.

I tried even using `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["language"].ToString();`

But no luck.

Below is the code sample where i am trying to catch the querystring

```
int LangID = 1;
int ArticleID = 0;
int PageID = 0;
int IssueID = 0;
int CategoryID = 0;
string language = string.Empty;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["PageID"]))
    {

        language = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["language"].ToString();
        LangID = Helper.GetLanguageID(language);
        ArticleID = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["aid"].ToString());
        PageID = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["PageID"].ToString());
        IssueID = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["issue"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        language = Request["language"];
        LangID = Helper.GetLanguageID(language);
        ArticleID = int.Parse(Request["aid"]);
        PageID = int.Parse(Request["PageID"]);
        IssueID = int.Parse(Request["issue"]);
    }
```

I am getting following error for this statement
`language = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["language"].ToString();`

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
System.NullReferenceException was caught
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=App_Web_odw0cnkk
```

I would appreciate help in this regarding or how to get around this problem

Comment: Have you tried this.Page.RouteData.Values["language"].ToString(); ?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["language"] is null

Comment: @jbl:- i tried `Page.RouteData.Values["language"].ToString();` that doent work either..

Comment: @SatPal:- You are right i am using `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["language"]))` now as language is present in all the pages. Basic thing which i missed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use as below:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["XXXXXX"]
```

Thx: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/tr-TR/c53d8d15-19d0-455b-b5a9-3d64d0793f99/usercontrol-iinde-routedatavaluesid?forum=aspnettr&prof=required